# Podcast syncing changed?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ios

I can't seem to get my podcasts to sync like they used to (before ios5).

I have iTunes set up to only transfer SELECTED UNPLAYED podcasts... however, it keeps transferring all of the SELECTED podcasts, played or not.

Do others have this same issue? If not, any suggestions on how I could get it to stop?

I've tried disabling, and re-enabling podcast syncing. Turning off and on SELECTED... turning off and on UNPLAYED... but this doesn't seem to resolve it.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely feel your pain when dealing with managing podcasts with iTunes on iOS devices. With the challenges of either creating a smart playlist that I can't then order (at least I've generally found this to be impossible) or the idea of having to micromanage my podcasts through a standard playlist as well as the oddities of what podcasts get synced and why I've generally given up.

What I recommend is a specific podcasting app. There are a few out there. I started with [Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast), but it became a little unstable for me recently. I've since gone to [Podcaster](http://podcaster.fm/), and aside from the initial learning curve, I like it more. The nice thing about either of them is that you never have to use iTunes to sync your podcasts either, as they'll download them over wifi or 3G.

Sorry that I can't provide a solution directly related to your iTunes challenge, but I've been happier going this route and maybe you would be as well.

Comment: OK - I'll check those out. I like keeping older ones on the computer - maybe I can figure out a new way to make it all play together nicely :)

Comment: +1 for Podcaster - it's been very liberating to get updating podcasts every day, direct to my device, without having to sync via iTunes...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. All podcasts either played or unplayed sync from device to computer. You must manually delete old podcast from device.

Comment: Good to know that I'm not alone in this... perhaps the promised version upgrade will help.